# how to fetch an event from one separate controller to another page controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

We've tried to fetch the broadcast event from a page controller to another using this code.

```
Controller1.js
    scope.createList = function() {
        scope.$broadcast("event: list updated", true);
    }

Controller2.js
   scope.$on("event: list updated", function(value) {
      console.log('event update");
   });
```

This method is working within one page controller, but not in separate js controllers. How can the controller2.js be notified by the controller1.js?

Comment: You could use a service/provider to share data

Answer (score 1):

*$broadcast* method emits events for all children scopes, so listener controller should be among them. Instead of broadcasting on scope, you can do it on *$rootScope* instead, so every scope will be able to catch the event.

```
.controller("Controller1", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.createList = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("event: list updated", true);
    }
})
```